# java KeyListener not responding?

Tags: java

I have this code the green square is meant to move but it doesn't I have done everything right. its just the key listen doesn't seem to be responding. I think there's a error around

addKeyListener(this); in the paintComponent in my Graphics class can you please help and tell me how to fix it and what's wrong.

my Main class

```
   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class Main {

static int v = 50;
    static int t = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("window");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(400,200);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Graphics object = new Graphics();

frame.add(object);
while (v > t){
object.Drawing();
}
}
     }
```

my Graphics class

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

     import javax.swing.*;

    public class Graphics extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

     int x = 0, y= 0, xx = 100, yy = 0, ltyx = 0, ltyyxx = 0, px = 0, py = 0;

public void Drawing(){
    repaint();
        }

public void paintComponent (java.awt.Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent (g);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
     g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(px, py, 25, 25);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(xx, yy, 50, 50);
    g.drawString("times looped around screen Blue : " + ltyx , 10, 10);
    g.drawString("Red : " + ltyyxx , 170, 20);

    x++;
    xx++;
    if (x > 400){
    x = 0;
    y += 50;
    }
    if (xx > 400){
        xx = 0;
        yy += 50;
        }
    if (y > 200){
    y = 0;
    ltyx++;
    }  
    if (yy > 200){
            yy = 0;
            ltyyxx++;
            }
    }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:{
        px++;
    break;
    }
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:{
        px--;
    break;
      }
     case KeyEvent.VK_UP:{
py++;
     break;
     }
     case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:{
py--;
     break;
     }
    }
}

         public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:{
        px = 0;
    break;
    }
     case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:{
        px = 0;
    break;
     }
     case KeyEvent.VK_UP:{
py = 0;
     break;
     }
     case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:{
py = 0;
     break;
     }
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Did you even search the forum before asking the question??? This question is asked daily. Did you look at the postings under the `Related` section on the right side of this page??? Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`!!!

Answer (score 2):

In user interfaces there is the concept of 'focus'. Only the component currently holding the focus directly receives key events. This is how for example, when typing, one text box on screen responds and not any other.

After `frame.add(object);`, add:

```
object.setFocusable(true);
object.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Also, the `addKeyListener(this);` call is in quite the wrong place. It will add another key listener every time it paints the component. It should be called only once, ideally in the constructor of the panel.

Comment: +1 - Adding a disclaimer and recommending Key Binding (plus a link of some description) instead of `KeyListener` would make this answer perfect.